# When the listitems are scrolled fast, setOnScrollListener is not working

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I tried to implement the sticky header listview described in the tutorial from

http://javatechig.com/android/listview-header-parallax-with-sticky-view-in-android

The problem is when I scroll the list very fast, the header doesnot move to the top of screen as desired.

I tried logging the value of **topY** and **heroTopY** in the following method.

```
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            /* Check if the first item is already reached to top.*/
            if (view.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
                View firstChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
                topY = 0;
                if (firstChild != null) {
                    topY = firstChild.getTop();
                    Log.d("topY", "" + topY);
                }

                heroTopY = stickyViewSpacer.getTop();
                Log.e("heroTopY", "" + heroTopY);
                Log.d("topY,heroTopY", topY + "," + heroTopY);
                stickyView.setY(Math.max(0, heroTopY + topY));

                // Set the image to scroll half of the amount that of ListView
                heroImageView.setY(topY * 0.5f);
            }
        }
```

The log output is:

```
09-01 17:35:23.692  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY﹕ 0
09-01 17:35:23.692  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview E/heroTopY﹕ 500
09-01 17:35:23.692  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY,heroTopY﹕ 0,500
09-01 17:35:23.856  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY﹕ -29
09-01 17:35:23.856  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview E/heroTopY﹕ 500
09-01 17:35:23.856  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY,heroTopY﹕ -29,500
09-01 17:35:23.873  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY﹕ -72
09-01 17:35:23.873  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview E/heroTopY﹕ 500
09-01 17:35:23.873  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY,heroTopY﹕ -72,500
09-01 17:35:23.892  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY﹕ -84
09-01 17:35:23.892  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview E/heroTopY﹕ 500
09-01 17:35:23.892  19530-19530/com.javatechig.parallaxlistview D/topY,heroTopY﹕ -84,500
```

As seen from the log output the topY value get stucked at 84 and so the header.
[image]
How to solve this??Any solution would be helpful!!!

Comment: add `Log.e` in the beginning of `onScroll`

Comment: With `if (view.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0){}`, you're moving your `stickyView` only when you reach the top, is that what you want?

Comment: @Rami, sir here is the link of video https://youtu.be/eyWDkwVnYxo. I wanted to achieve the header **Heading1** stick to the top as the first item of listview reaches the top of screen,its working fine if the scrolling is done slowly.But if scrolled fast the **Heading1** view doesnot move to the top!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these lines

```
if (view.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
.....
.....
}
else
{
  stickyView.setY(0);
}
```

It is because when 1st item gets out of view you dont get inside if statement means topY is not updated so you have to set your stickyView.setY() to 0 on else statement.